# Tkinter global event handler

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a complex dynamic GUI with tkinter, the option for my use case would be a global event handler where I can decide on which `widget` and `event` type I want to process. I tried the following code, obviously it does not work. How can I achieve that?

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

def global_handler(widget, event):
   pass

root.bind_all('any', global_handler) # This does not work

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

def global_handler(event):
   print(f"{event.type}") # 4 is Button. 2 is KeyPress.
   # https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-types.html

root.bind_all('<1>', global_handler) #all widget binding. event.type = 4
root.bind_all('<Key>', global_handler) #all keyboard binding. event.type = 2

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This solution doesn't handle key release events, button release events, or any button other than the first mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

I found this website very useful to learn more about the bind eventhandling:

https://python-course.eu/tkinter/events-and-binds-in-tkinter.php

What I know is, that you should specify every event carefully. Otherwise, you have a very bad structure and a not so responsive GUI.

For example, if you have to detect a Keypress from the Enter-Button:

```
root.bind(sequence= '<Return>', func= start_event)
```

This Event-Function will only start, when the Enter-Key was pressed, as long as it is in the root-window. You could also specify that to Buttons, Entries, etc...

You can start functions outside of a Spinbox for example:

```
spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(root, from_= 0, to= 10, textvariable= i, command= start_event)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, this isn't how tkinter isn't designed to work, and there's no way to make it work that way.

There is no way to bind to every event in a single statement, or even with a dozen statements. The `bind` statement requires one specific event, so you'll have to have one bind statement for almost every possible event you want to catch. You can bind to all key presses and all key releases, but you still have to bind to the press and release events separately.

If all you care about is mouse buttons and key presses, you can get fairly close with the following:

```
root.bind_all('<Any-KeyPress>', global_handler)
root.bind_all('<Any-KeyRelease>', global_handler)
root.bind_all('<Any-ButtonPress>', global_handler)
root.bind_all('<Any-ButtonRelease>', global_handler)
```

That won't catch any other events though, so you'll have to add additional bindings for all of the other things you want to handle (eg: `<FocusIn>`, `<FocusOut>`, `<MouseWheel>`, `<Enter>`, `<Leave>`, and some others).

Speaking with decades of experience, trying to do what you want to do will be likely be more difficult to write, more difficult to understand, more difficult to debug, and more difficult to maintain over time than to use them in the way they are intended to be used.